# RingtoneManager sometimes returns wrong ringtone

Tags: android

I have a couple of ringtones, distributed with APK file and access them the following way

```
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(mContext, uri);

    if (r != null) {
        r.setStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION);
        r.play();
    }
```

In most cases this works as expected but in some devices system plays incorrect ringtone that was not supposed to be ever played. After short investigation I found out that documentation for the RingtoneManager.getRingtone method says that

```
 If the given URI cannot be opened for any reason, this method will attempt to fallback on another sound. If it cannot find any, it will return null.
```

That means that I cannot ever be sure that returned ringtone I the one I have asked for. So my question is how can I at least verify that getRingtone method has returned me another(default) ringtone so that I could at least not play it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the whole job of RingtoneManager is to do said fallback, so if that's not what you want, consider playing your audio using [android.media.MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).